# Maven : ear of pom.xml : bind properties for web.xml in all wars

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, pom.xml, web.xml

I'll explain my title :

I have one maven EAR project which contains wars.
in the pom of my ear, I added that code :

```
<properties>
    <app_url>http://localhost</app_url>
    <app_port>8080</app_port>
    <app_name>MyApp</app_name>
</properties>
```

In my web.xml files in some war in my ear, I added this :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Some filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>service</param-name>
        <param-value>${app_url}:${app_port}/${app_name}</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

When I build my EAR project with maven, nothing is replaced in my web.xml files.
Is there something i missed ?

Thanks in advance for your responses :)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your WARs contain the web.xml files. And your EAR contains the values to be used for replacement of properties. That cannot work like that. By default, your EAR module will just package itself with the WARs, without modifying them.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly.
Is there a way to modifying any files in a war in a pom.xml of the ear project ?

Comment: Well, although this is technically possible, the EAR plugin works with dependencies (or at least with artifacts present on the local repository), so that would require a process that unpacks a WAR, filters it, repacks it and installs it on the local repository. Is there any reason for these values not to be replaced when generating the WAR itself?